# AC circuit to model blood flow - circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

The Windkessel model is used to model cardiovascular flow. It models arteries, which can store blood, as capacitors, and peripheral vessels (which resist flow due to contact of the fluid with the vessel wall), as resistors. Below is the 3 element Windkessel model, figure from "Model of Aortic Blood Flow" (Catanho, Sinha, Vijayan):

[3 Element Windkessel - 2 impedance elements, 1 capacitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plB6u.jpg)

My question is, how do you derive the equation for P(t), an AC element, which represents blood pressure in the pulmonary artery? This is essentially a circuit analysis question.

Here is what I tried:

\$I(t) = -P(t)/r\$

\$I(t) = C*dP(t)/dt + P(t)/R \$

\$-P(t)/r = C*dP(t)/dt + P(t)/R\$

\$-P(t)/r - P(t)/R= C*dP(t)/dt\$

However, this is different from the equation in the paper:

\$(1 + r/R)*i(t) + CR_1*di(t)/dt = P(t)/R + C*dP(t)/dt\$

How did they derive this equation from the circuit?

Comment: The \$R_1\$ in your last equation should be \$r\$.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, with the overall impedance of this circuit being Z
$$
I = P / Z = \dfrac{P}{r+\dfrac{1}{sC + 1/R }}=P\cdot\dfrac{sC+1/R}{r(sC+1/R)+1}
$$
Which is equivalent to
$$
  I \left( rsC+r/R+1 \right) = P (sC+1/R)
$$
So, your book is right.

In case you are not familiar with the Laplace transform you can replace the s with d/dt.